# How to copy a formula down so the cell locations within the formula stay even or odd numbered cells only in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sum formula that finds the sum of cells across many tabs in my sheet. It basically looks like this:

```
=SUM(tab1!M1, tab2!M1, tab3!M1, tab4!M1, tab5!M1, etc)
```

When I drag this formula down, it will adjust the cells within the formula accordingly, one cell at a time, like this:

```
=SUM(tab1!M2 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M3 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M4 etc)
```

And so on down. I'd like to instead be able to copy down this formula so it sticks with either odd cells or even cells. Like this:

```
=SUM(tab1!M2 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M4 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M6 etc)
```

or

```
=SUM(tab1!M1 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M3 etc)
=SUM(tab1!M5 etc)
```

Is this possible? Or am I stuck manually adjusting the formulas in every row?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it, one is to use an operation with the number of the row of the cell. For example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Tab1!M"&ROW()*2),INDIRECT("Tab2!M"&ROW()*2).....)
```

When you drag it will do it by two rows per row.

Other option without dragging:

```
=BYROW(FILTER({Tab1!M1:M1000,Tab2!M1:M1000....},ISODD(Row (Tab!M1:M1000))),LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)))
```

Other optiom that can be dragged similar to the first one but without having to rewrite everything for every new tab:

```
=REDUCE(0,{"Tab1","Tab2","Tab3"...}, LAMBDA(a,v,a+INDIRECT(v&"!M"&ROW()*2)))
```

And there are more combinations of these priors. Try them!